# TF warnings won't silence

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am doing Hyperparameter Optimization with ray tune but all the time I got TF warnings

```
WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform <function quaternion_mean_multiplicative_error at 0x7f22be6808b0> and will run it as-is.  
(BroadModel pid=597696) Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. 
(BroadModel pid=597696) Cause: Unknown node type <gast.gast.Import object at 0x7f22640d4190>  
(BroadModel pid=597696) To silence this warning, decorate the function with @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
```

Also I use all these codes:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import types
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import logging
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
os.environ["KMP_AFFINITY"] = "noverbose"
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

def tensorflow_shutup():
    """
    Make Tensorflow less verbose
    """
    try:
        os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

        # noinspection PyPackageRequirements
        import tensorflow as tf
        from tensorflow.python.util import deprecation

        tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)

        # Monkey patching deprecation utils to shut it up! Maybe good idea to disable this once after upgrade
        # noinspection PyUnusedLocal
        def deprecated(date, instructions, warn_once=True):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
            def deprecated_wrapper(func):
                return func
            return deprecated_wrapper

        deprecation.deprecated = deprecated

    except ImportError:
        pass
```

But still, I am getting all warnings. It is so annoying.
Is there any other way to silence tensorflow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've also experienced issues where logging does not behave as expected in TensorFlow, so it's likely this is an issue in the library.

First thing to confirm is that you are on the latest version of TensorFlow. [This](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/56865) appears to be a similar issue that occurred in TF 2.7.0 but not in TF >= 2.8.2, so if you are on an older version then upgrading may be enough to resolve it.

If not, why not report to the TensorFlow team like the warning suggests? You can do that [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues).